# MYSQL UPDATE query that does delete the row instead, if updated value meets condition

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-delete

I'd like to make a one-query ask to database that will update records, but if one specific record after this change is equal to 0, I'd like to remove this row. Is it possible? Example:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `row1`=`row1`+5, `row2`=`row2`+30 IF (row1 after the update == 0) DELETE WHERE `primarycolumn`=1
```

Obviously, the `IF (row1 after the change == 0) DELETE` part is just pseudocode that does not work - is it possible to create a query that will make it work that way?

Comment: No. There is no query type in MySQL which combines UPDATE and DELETE actions. But you may solve your task by using stored procedure instead of single query.

Comment: But there is an IF statement, that I do have trouble with. I'm sure that there will be a way to use it. Perhaps I should not write "one-query" - what I mean is, to make this with only one mysqli connection from php. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `IF` statement may be used in some compound statement only. and stored procedure is one of them.

Comment: I was thinking about something like `IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE primarycolumn=1 AND row1=-5) THEN {DELETE ...} ELSE {UPDATE ...}` - since I know, that when I'm adding +5 to row1, I'll get there 0 if it's current value is -5. But this code above does not work and I have no idea what is the correct statement...

Comment: You may think about this, of course - but there is no anonymous blocks in MySQL...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to update and then check if `row1 = 0`.
Delete with this condition:

```
DELETE FROM `table` 
WHERE `primarycolumn` = 1 AND `row1` + 5 = 0
```

If the condition fails then nothing will be deleted.
Then do the `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE `table` 
SET `row1`= `row1`+ 5, `row2` = `row2` + 30 
WHERE `primarycolumn` = 1
```

If the row was not deleted it will be updated, but if it was deleted then nothing will be updated.

Comment: I was kinda asking about other solution, but this is not only clever, but will work for me. Exactly what I was looking for, even if I did not know that it was the case!

Comment: You don't need to always send the update statement. On the Delete statement you can check the property affectedRows (may depend on the library or language you use). If the affectedRows count is higher or not equal to 0 then don't update.